# What is the difference between “un Italien” and “une Italienne”?

Tags: genre

What is the difference between those two sentences?

> un Italien
>
> une Italienne

When do we use *un* and *une*? They both mean *a* in English, right? But, why are they used differently?

Comment: Hey dude, where's my punchline ? Talk about a joke bait / accidental innuendo. I'm so proud I (sort of) resisted it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

French divides nouns in [genders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_gender). More specifically, in French, a noun can be *masculine* or *feminine*.

Usually, nouns which refer to a man are masculine, when nouns which refer to a woman are feminine. Some word which can refer to one or the other have two forms: one masculine, one feminine. This is the case for “Italien/Italienne”.

“*Italien*” thus means “Italian man”, “*Italienne*” means “Italian woman”.

Moreover, articles, adjectives, pronouns, … agree (in gender and number) with the nouns they refer to. In the case of the indefinite article (which matches the “a” in English), the masculine is “*un*” and the feminine is “*une*”.

Thus, ”un Italien” is “an Italian man” and “une Italienne” is “an Italian woman”.